# Windows 2003 Server packets from WAN/NAT not going to application

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003, openvpn

I have a Windows 2003 Server where I installed openvpn.

To avoid any openvpn config issue, I used miniweb (a simple http server) and I have the same problem with that.

The issue is that I can connect to the server from the LAN, but when I access it from the wan, I have no access. I used network monitor to scan the queries and answers.

- From the LAN I have the regular exchange for an http query.
- From the WAN I only have one packet in, and the server responds, but it never gets to the client.

It is not blocked by the router, as with the "same" config (program and port) on my Windows 7 machine, it works.

I connected the server directly to the router to avoid any sneaky switch blocking rules.

The only difference between the NAT config for my Windows 7 machine and my server is the IP.

The Windows firewall is disabled and there's no antivirus.

The server is listening on all IPs.

I also tried on a windows XP machine, it works with no problems.

IIS is installed on the server, maybe there's a rule I didn't find that blocks remote access to the whole server?

What could I do to connect to that server from the WAN (internet)?

edit: A workaround I found to work was putting a debian vm (in bridge mode) on that pc,and installing openvpn on that. Though, I would still like to have the answer to what is causing that.

Comment: netstat -a and check openvpn actually has the port open for a start. Then make sure that port is open on your router by scanning it from an external IP (many sites can do this for you, shieldsup is one that springs to mind).

Comment: I've got   `TCP    SERVER-NAME:8000   SERVER-NAME.domain.local:0  listening` for the test webserver and `UDP    SERVER-NAME:1194   *:* ` for openvpn.

Comment: Have you looked at IPv6?

Comment: @Burgi 2k3 doesn't support IPv6 afaik

Comment: Exactly, Win7 does and your Win7 version is working.

Comment: not a windows version problem, I checked on a windows XP machine, it works.